# Stop double division before decimals (low precision, fast division; getting only the 'quotient')

Tags: c++, performance, division

Basically a performance related question:

I want to get only the integer quotient from a double division, i.e. for example, for a division `88.3/12.7 = 6.9527559055118110236220472440945`, I only want to get '6' as a result.
A possible implementation would be of course: `floor(x/y)`, but here, first the performance-intensive double division is done and afterwards floor throws away most of the 'work' the double division did.

So basically I want a division with doubles which 'stops' before calculating all these decimal points and just gives me the correct integer result of the division, without rounding or truncating the initial double arguments. Does anyone know an elegant implementation for this (I searched for this topic but didn't find much)?

Another implementation I can imagine is:
`int(x*1000)/int(y*1000)`
Where instead of 1000, the needed 'precision' can be used. A very simple implementation would be also simply subtracting y from x until the result is smaller than zero. But yeah, I was wondering what would be the best way to do it.

Also, doing simply `int(x)/int(y)` is no option since it could easily result in wrong results.

By the way, I know this is probably again one of these 'micro-optimization' questions which deal with a matter that does not really matter on new machines, but well, I still am kinda curious on the subject! :-)

Comment: Integer and floating point division take the same time.  32-bit division is faster than 64-bit division. If the denominator is limited enough that you could have a lookup table to get the reciprocal then a multiply is much faster.

Comment: The problem is that you can't really just do a "part" of the division to get the non-fractional number. At least I think so, since I'm not that good at advanced math. Unless you absolutely want code, then perhaps ask on http://math.stackexchange.com/ for how to only get the non-fractional part of a division?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to stop earlier, and using integer division is potentially slower.

For example, on Skylake:

```
idiv r/m32 L: 26-27 T: 6
divsd xmm, xmm L: 13-14 T: 4
```

([source](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00506E3_Skylake_InstLatX64.txt))

So the double division is twice as fast and has a significantly better throughput. That is *before* you factor in the extra multiplications and extra cast.

On older µarchs, 32 bit integer division often has lower latency numbers listed than double division, *but* they varied more (division used to be more serial), with (for floats) round divisors being faster yet for integer division it's small results that are faster. This difference in characteristics can make it swing either way, depending on what you're dividing by what.

As you can see it's dangerous in this case to optimize without a specific target in mind, but I imagine newer machines are a more likely target than older machines, which means the double division is more or less the best you can do anyway (unless other optimizations apply). Dividing single precision floats is faster by itself but incurs a conversion cost, it actually ends up losing (5+10) if you add them up.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. As someone who is closer to mathematics/physics than programming, I am amazed that integer division can be slower than float/double division.

Comment: @kushy prepare to be even more amazed: 64 bit integer division typically (as in, across most µarchs) takes up to 90 cycles. Completely off the charts. Anyway I guess it's largely a matter of focus, I'm relatively sure that they *could* make 32bit integer division at least as fast as double division (I mean, there are fewer bits to divide, sort of.. depends on which operand you look at. At the very least, it doesn't need to be twice as slow), but choose not to.